# Pandas Group By Weird Behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
def quant(X,col_):
    print('X\n',X.head(5))
    q25 = np.quantile(X[col_],0.15)
    q75 = np.quantile(X[col_],0.85)
    total = X[col_].tolist()
    ltq = []
    mtq = []
    iqr = []
    for i in total:
        if i < q25:
            ltq.append(i)
        elif i > q75:
            mtq.append(i)
        else:
            iqr.append(i)
    p_l_q = 100*(len(ltq))/len(total)
    p_l_m = 100*(len(mtq))/len(total)
    percent_iqr = 100*len((iqr))/len(total)
    X['p_l_q'] = p_l_q
    X['p_l_m'] = p_l_m
    X['p_l_i'] = percent_iqr
    X['count'] = len(total)
    X_short = X[['p_l_q','p_l_m','p_l_i','count']].copy(deep = True)
    print(X_short[:1])
    new = X_short[:1]
    return new


X = pd.DataFrame()
X['G'] = ''
X['H'] = ''
X['M'] = ''
lst1 = ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
lst2 = [10,12,13,45,52,34,78,34,56,79,90,65,56,43,11]
lst3 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]
X['G'] = lst1
X['H'] = lst2
X['M'] = lst3



X_q = X.groupby('G').apply(quant,'H').reset_index()
```

I have used a print statement to give me head of dataframe block for each unique 'G' but I get weird print like in image.
There should be exactly three print outputs.(for each unqiue G) but it is showing 5 on top of that second print output (G='b') has H values as that of G ='a'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
def quant(X,col_):
    print('X\n',X.head(5))
```

With this:

```
def quant(XX,col_):
    X = XX.copy()
    print('X\n',XX.head(5))
    del XX # Delete 'XX' because 'X' copy is available
```

Output

[image]